# Redefine Variable in Function For a Certain Part

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var $name=prompt("In order for this page to work, we just need a piece of information. Please enter your first name.");
var $age=prompt("Please enter your new age.")

function startSong() {
    var a = 'Happy birthday to you';
    $("#btext").html(a).fadeIn(2000);
    window.scrollBy(0, 200);
    $("#btext").fadeOut(2000);
    $("#btext").html(a).fadeIn(2000);
    a = 'Happy birthday to you, ' + $name;
    $("#btext").fadeOut(2000);
    $("#btext").html(a).fadeIn(2000)

}
```

I want it to first print out 'Happy birthday to you' twice, and then print out 'Happy birthday to (name)'. However, it seems to skip right to the redefinition of the variable.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<button onclick="startSong()">Now, we all want to sing you Happy Birthday! Go on and click this button!</button>
<h5 id=btext> </h5>
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you create a working example using snippets , or post the relevant html part so we can do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#btext").html(a)` calls and the assignments to `a` do not wait for the preceding fade effects to finish. So all of those statements are going to happen even though the effects previously set have not yet finished. They are asynchrounous operations

the fade* calls can be passed a callback to let code run when the effect has finished. Put your code in the correct fade* callbacks to get your expected operation:

```
$("#btext").html(a).fadeIn(2000,function(){
  window.scrollBy(0, 200);
  $("#btext").fadeOut(2000,function(){
    $("#btext").html(a).fadeIn(2000,function(){
      //and so on
    });
  });
});
```

Obviously this can lead to [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)

So you can alternatively [queue your actions](https://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue-queueName-callback) in between the fade* effects:

```js
function startSong() {
  let btext = $("#btext");
  let a = "Happy birthday to you"; 
  let $name = "Stackoverflow";
  btext.html(a)
       //internally adds the effect to the fx queue
       .fadeIn(2000)
       //internally adds the effect to the fx queue
       .fadeOut(2000)
       //adds the code to change the html to fx queue
       //executes when the previous queue item is done
       .queue(function(next) {
         btext.html(a);
         //call next to let the queue advance to the next item
         next();
       })
       .fadeIn(2000)
       .fadeOut(2000)
       .queue(function(next) {
         a = 'Happy birthday to you, ' + $name;
         btext.html(a);
         next();
        })
        .fadeIn(2000);
}
```

```css
#btext {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="startSong()">Now, we all want to sing you Happy Birthday! Go on and click this button!</button>
<h5 id=btext> </h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use callbacks to delay each fadeIn/fadeOut until the previous one finished.

```js
var $name = prompt("In order for this page to work, we just need a piece of information. Please enter your first name.");
var $age = prompt("Please enter your new age.")

function startSong() {
  var a = 'Happy birthday to you';
  $("#btext").html(a).fadeIn(2000, function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 200);
    $("#btext").fadeOut(2000, function() {
      $("#btext").html(a).fadeIn(2000, function() {
        a = 'Happy birthday to you, ' + $name;
        $("#btext").fadeOut(2000, function() {
          $("#btext").html(a).fadeIn(2000);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="startSong()">Now, we all want to sing you Happy Birthday! Go on and click this button!</button>
<h5 id=btext> </h5>
```